# Giving different titles to plots in for-loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

D = 12
n = np.arange(1,4)
x = np.linspace(-D/2,D/2, 3000)
I = np.array([125,300,75])
phase = np.genfromtxt('8phases.txt')

I_phase = I*phase

for count,i in enumerate(I_phase):
    F = sum(m*np.cos(2*np.pi*l*x/D) for m,l in zip(i,n))
    f = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.plot(x,F)
    plt.savefig(str(count)+'.png')
plt.show()
```

This script generates 8 plots and also saves them. I want to give all the plots different titles. Is it possible that it will read a `.txt` or Excel file (`.xls`) and take the title directly from there for each plot? For example; I have titles like these (can be saved either as `.txt` or `.xls` file):

```
phase_01_water
phase_02_membrane
phase_03_water
phase_04_empty
phase_05_water
phase_06_water
phase_07_full
phase_08_water
```

How can I do that? The `'8phases.txt'` has the following 8 lines:

```
-1     1    -1
-1     1     1
 1     1     1
 1    -1     1
-1    -1    -1
 1     1    -1
 1    -1    -1
-1    -1     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can if the titles are in a simple txt file as in your example, you can simply load them with something like this

```
with open('titles_file.txt') as f:
    titlelist = f.readlines()
```

Then `matplotlib.Axes` have a method `set_title`. I also rewrite your for loop in a more object oriented way

```
for count,i in enumerate(I_phase):
    F = sum(m*np.cos(2*np.pi*l*x/D) for m,l in zip(i,n))
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_title(titlelist[count])
    ax.plot(x,F)
    fig.savefig(str(count)+'.png')
```

Comment: hi, in your answer, is titlelist should be the .txt file containing all the title. I did it that way but it says name 'titlelist' is not defined.

Comment: I know that `titlelist` is not defined. I assumed that you could read the file and store its content in a python list. I've edited the answer

Comment: thank you. I actually manage it right now. it was my stupidity that I didn't read the file in the first place.